# Scanning BarCode from Web Application on Motorola Symbol MC9100

Tags: jquery, motorola

I am trying to run an application as a web application on Motorola MC 9100 device. 
I have a requirement to invoke the device scanner on focus of a text box on the web app. 
Please let me know if that is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***DataWedge***. It leaves the scanner available at any time, you can easily configure it to add a *prefix* or a *sufix* to the decoded barcode and you can choose what types of barcodes you want the device to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datawedge to get data but it will just stream whatever you scan as though it was typed at the keyboard.  There is no control of when it is on within an application.

Motorola provides an EMDK (Enterprise Mobile Development Kit).  Their version of an SDK.

There are tools that can be used within their enterprise browser to accomplish this.  Motorola provides a nice set of Javascript tools within the browser to accomplish things just like this.  Because they are the creator of all pieces they have set it up to give access beyond what would normally be allowed.  Primarily focused on interacting with the hardware.